# How to create list of nums on the start of the project

Tags: asp.net, events, project

I've have such code:

```
namespace _namespace
{

    public enum Enums
    {
        Value1 = 1,

        Value2 = 2,

        Value13 = 3,

        ...

        Valuen = n
    }
}
```

All this datum are already in database. All what I need it's to create the list of enums on the start of the project.

P.S. It's web applicat

Comment: Hmm.. if you need to create enums - create it. What is the question? Where is the problem?

Comment: @Samich The OP has the pairs already located in the database. He wants to generate the Enum on the fly based on the DB values.

Comment: It's impossible. He can write `one-time` utility for generating code and put it in the project. Also it can be used some dictionary - but it's not enum behaviour anymore.

Answer (score 3):

An Enum is not meant to be dynamic. This is not something that can/should be done in your application. You can create a `Dictionary<int, string>` to work with your database values.

Comment: All is needed it's to get the datum ones. I mean not to ask the database for every user, it must be done ones. Is't possible?

Comment: not as an Enum. Poll the database on application start, and store it in a shared `Dictionary<int, string>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use T4 to generate the enum from a lookup table

http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html